# Handle error and fail message

Tags: node.js

I am using promise. I want to know what is the best practice to handle fail and error.

```
return Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Query User by Id 1
    User.FindById('1').then(result=> {
       if(result) throw Error('No result found'); // fail 
       resolve(result);
    }).catch(err => {
       // how to differentiate this is error or fail?
       if(err.status = 'fail') {
          // fail
          error = "...";
       } else {
          // serious error
          error = "...";
       }
       reject(error)
    });
}
```

How is my practice?